# Forms 9.3 Multi-step chunking with conditional logic

Tags: sitecore-forms

I've asked this several months ago when 9.1 was transitioning to 9.2

Now with 9.3 is multi-step chunking with conditional form logic and progress feasible this time around?

**https://xd.adobe.com/view/8be4c4f1-ce01-4f3a-4bea-577b38bd4a66-fdd5 Here's a wireframe for more context.** Click on the canvas to move to the next screen.

Form extensions could potentially do the job. However looking at OOB solution only at this stage

[image: Example Form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible OOTB at the moment (Sitecore 9.3 Initial Release). The conditions currently only look at the page the form elements are on.

This means that if I select Option A in page 1, I can't see that (OOTB) in Page 2.

Comment: Cheers for confirming Trayek. Our Sitecore rep said this would happen in 9.3 Could this be done using form extensions or only the custom route?

Comment: I'm not certain Forms Extensions can handle this - I've only quickly went through https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions though, I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue for the progression bar with multiple steps Forms in Sitecore 9.3.

I ended up adding the whole progression bar html on each pages(forms chunk) using the OOTB Text Field with an extra **CssClass** that will be used within the view (here I am using "***rawHtml***". Then overwrite the **TextField view** (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourInstance\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\Text.cshtml`) with this :

```
@model Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.TextViewModel

@if (Model.CssClass.Contains("rawHtml"))
{
    @Html.Raw(Model.Text)
}
else
{
    <div class="parametric-richtext-container ">
        <@Model.HtmlTag data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" class="@Model.CssClass">@Model.Text</@Model.HtmlTag>
    </div>
}
```

Your html chunk should have a currentClass, completedClass, etc and assign those on each chunk accordingly. Ex :

For chunk 1,

```
<div class="form-steps">
    <p class="form-step is-current">
        <span>Step 1</span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-step">
        <span>Step 2</span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-step">
        <span>Step 3</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

For chunk 2,

```
<div class="form-steps">
    <p class="form-step is-completed">
        <span>Step 1</span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-step is-current">
        <span>Step 2</span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-step">
        <span>Step 3</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

For chunk 3,

```
<div class="form-steps">
    <p class="form-step is-completed">
        <span>Step 1</span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-step is-completed">
        <span>Step 2</span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-step is-current">
        <span>Step 3</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

For chunk 4 or thank you message or whatever,

```
<div class="form-steps">
    <p class="form-step is-completed">
        <span>Step 1</span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-step is-completed">
        <span>Step 2</span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-step is-completed">
        <span>Step 3</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

With the pages(forms chunk) being hidden/show within the previous/next navigation, it worked out pretty well.